# AWS AppSync Javascript Subscription throws 404 Error

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-appsync

Hi I'm trying to subscribe to AWS AppSync using JS with this example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/building-a-client-app-javascript.html

When querying user table, I got the result just fine. But I can't seem to subscribe to new results.

What I got is a 404 error:

```
https://some-iot-url.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mqtt?X-Amz-Algorithm=..... 404 (Not Found)
```

with the following error:

> errorCode:7
>
> errorMessage:"AMQJS0007E Socket error:undefined."
>
> invocationContext:undefined

The strange thing about the IOT url is that it doesn't match with my IOT url in the IoT core dashboard. Is this expected?

More info: I bundled the code with webpack (but I guess this has nothing to do with the error)

Here's my full code

## config.js

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var config = {
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: '',
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: '',
    HOST: 'my-host.appsync-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
    REGION: 'eu-west-1',
    PATH: '/graphql',
    ENDPOINT: '',
};
config.ENDPOINT = "https://" + config.HOST + config.PATH;
exports.default = config;
```

## app.js

```
/**
* This shows how to use standard Apollo client on Node.js
*/

global.WebSocket = require('ws');
global.window = global.window || {
    setTimeout: setTimeout,
    clearTimeout: clearTimeout,
    WebSocket: global.WebSocket,
    ArrayBuffer: global.ArrayBuffer,
    addEventListener: function () { },
    navigator: { onLine: true }
};
global.localStorage = {
    store: {},
    getItem: function (key) {
        return this.store[key]
    },
    setItem: function (key, value) {
        this.store[key] = value
    },
    removeItem: function (key) {
        delete this.store[key]
    }
};
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
require('isomorphic-fetch');

// Require exports file with endpoint and auth info
const aws_exports = require('./aws-exports').default;

// Require AppSync module
const AUTH_TYPE = require('aws-appsync/lib/link/auth-link').AUTH_TYPE;
const AWSAppSyncClient = require('aws-appsync').default;

const url = aws_exports.ENDPOINT;
const region = aws_exports.REGION;
const type = AUTH_TYPE.API_KEY;

// If you want to use API key-based auth
const apiKey = 'my-api-key';
// If you want to use a jwtToken from Amazon Cognito identity:
const jwtToken = 'xxxxxxxx';

// // If you want to use AWS...
// const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// AWS.config.update({
//     region: aws_exports.REGION,
//     credentials: new AWS.Credentials({
//         accessKeyId: aws_exports.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
//         secretAccessKey: aws_exports.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
//     })
// });
// const credentials = AWS.config.credentials;

// Import gql helper and craft a GraphQL query
const gql = require('graphql-tag');
const query = gql(`
query AllUser {
listUsers(first: 20) {
    __typename
        items{
        id
        userId
        username
    }
}
}`);

// Set up a subscription query
const subquery = gql(`
subscription NewUser {
subscribeToNewUsers {
    __typename
    id
    userId
    username
}
}`);

// Set up Apollo client
const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
    url: url,
    region: region,
    auth: {
        type: type,
        apiKey: apiKey,
    }
});

client.hydrated().then(function (client) {
    //Now run a query
    console.log('querying')
    client.query({ query: query })
        .then(function logData(data) {
            console.log('results of query: ', data);
        })
        .catch(console.error);

    //Now subscribe to results
    const observable = client.subscribe({ query: subquery });
    console.log(observable)
    const realtimeResults = function realtimeResults(data) {
        console.log('realtime data: ', data);
    };

    observable.subscribe({
        next: realtimeResults,
        complete: console.log,
        error: console.log,
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey sorry for the slow response. If you are running this in a browser context can you try commenting out the following lines of code:

```
/*
global.WebSocket = require('ws');
global.window = global.window || {
    setTimeout: setTimeout,
    clearTimeout: clearTimeout,
    WebSocket: global.WebSocket,
    ArrayBuffer: global.ArrayBuffer,
    addEventListener: function () { },
    navigator: { onLine: true }
};
global.localStorage = {
    store: {},
    getItem: function (key) {
        return this.store[key]
    },
    setItem: function (key, value) {
        this.store[key] = value
    },
    removeItem: function (key) {
        delete this.store[key]
    }
};
require('isomorphic-fetch');
*/

// You should be able to keep this.
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
```

This sample has some work arounds to make it work nicely with node but it seems like there are a few issues in its current state. Let me know if that works. Thanks!

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the version of the websocket library being used by that tutorial. I was able to reproduce the issue and saw that it was incorrectly prepending the URL returned by the AppSync subscription call with https:// instead of wss:// which caused the issue. If you open your dev tools network tab and click the request that is failing with the 404 you will see the https:// url. You can open that url in your browser and see the error payload. My hunch is that it is the websocket library at fault and defaulting to the browser's websocket impl works in this case.

Comment: OK! Thanks for the clarification!